# Solar flare charge?

Tags: solar-flare

Does a solar flare and/or accompanying coronal mass ejection have a net electrical charge?  If so, positive or negative?  And how much might that charge affect the Earth’s total net electrical potential?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257418/123208

Comment: No, nothing that lasts for any appreciable amount of time (i.e., electrons are very fast and neutralize charge imbalances very quickly).